# How to convert Z-Up vertices to Y-Up vertices without breaking the winding order of a mesh. (DX9c)

Tags: c++, mesh, direct3d, directx-9, id3dxmesh

I have a C++ DirectX9 rendering engine with Y as my up axis. When I import a model that was modeled with Z as the up axis I simply swap the Y and Z  values of all of the model's the vertices to have the model correctly orientated. This works fine except for the fact that the winding orders of most (not all) of the meshes are wrong.

Since I render the model with back face culling enabled, the outer shell of the models are invisible and the internal shells are visible.

I've inverted the indices in an attempt to rectify the problem, and it works fine...but since not all the models suffers from the same wrong winding order, I sit with half of the models with correct winding orders and the other half with incorrect winding orders.

So I guess my question then is: How do I correctly convert a 3d model with Z as its up axis to a 3d model with Y as its up axis without breaking the winding order in the process.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Swap the Y with -Z.

Answer (score 1):

Winding orders are wrong if you don't preserve the handedness of your coordinate system.  Typically, (x, y, z) is a RIGHT-HANDED coordinate system: that is, if you point your right thumb in the +x direction and your right index finger in the +y direction, curling the other three fingers naturally, they should point toward the +z direction.  You may have flipped your coordinates in a manner that changed the system from right-handed to left-handed.  (x,y,z) can be changed to (y,z,x) or (z,x,y), but the other permutations will demonstrate the wrong windedness.

Comment: Hi Bruce. Thank you for for the response. My engine uses a left handed coordinate system (direct3D) and the mesh that I have to import is from a right handed system... the following link describes nicely how to handle it when dealing with the exact case ...but my issue is that the data that I have to import is right handed and the up axis is Z. So I need to convert it for a left handed system with Y- up and keep the winding orders in tact.